# Comparing un-ordered dictionary values along with keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

We have 2 dictionary,i would like to apply following conditions and update the `old_x` with `new_x`

```
old_x = {"A":[1,2,3,4,5],"B":[],"C":[10,30]}
new_x = {"B":[3,4,5],"A":[1,5,3],"C":[30,10],"D":[2]}
```

1. ordering of the `elements` inside the `lists` values is not important.
   `ex: "C"`
2. ordering of `Keys` inside of dictionaries is not important.
   `ex: un-ordered keys in new_x`
3. Any new `Key` in `new_x` which is not present in `old_x` should be added to `old_x`.
   `ex: "D"`
4. updating the `old_x` value lists with `new_x` values if new element found in lists of `new_x`, similarly remove the `values` if `new_x` doesn't contain those values of `old_x`.
   `ex: "B" for updating, "A" for removing`

---

*Expected output on comparing:*

> old_x = {"A":[1,5,3],"B":[3,4,5],"C":[10,30],"D":[2]}

Please help me creating a function for this?

**Note: Elements & Keys in `new_x` is not always the same.I Kept them similar to demonstrate the keypoints of the problem.**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like new `old_x` is just `new_x`. I mean `new_x` and `Expected output` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of keys/values in arrays is not important, why not just call:

`old_x.update(new_x)`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this simply:

```
old_x = new_x
```

You can make a copy like this:

```
old_x = dict(new_x)
```